# Hide menu on specific page in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I am making my website in wordpress using astra theme. I have there 2 pages present, https://petrmacholan.cz/ and https://petrmacholan.cz/blog/ . Any of the pages I create on this website in present I would like my navigation menu hidden. How do I do that? What should I write in my css code to make it that way? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
#main-menu {
  display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Dashboard - Pages - Edit (specific) - Astra settings (right upper toolbar) - scroll down to Advanced settings - Disable primary header (disable all header, including logo, site title and menu) - close Astra advanced settings window - Update (button slose to Astra settings button (right upper toolbar).